# Needing to apply cream for medical reasons while at work

Tags: professionalism, health

I've got a doctor's appointment after work next week and will be heading straight from the office to see the doctor. In preparation for treatment, I need to apply cream to my foot an hour before the appointment. Given the logistics, I don't have enough time to go home to do this.

I work in a large office with many people. I feel a bit self conscious taking off my shoe and rubbing cream in my foot in front of everyone. I guess I can go to a bathroom stall and do it, but it would be a balancing act as the toilets don't have covers to sit on.

Any suggestions? Should I explain this to my supervisor and ask if there's a quiet place I could do this in? There's no change room where I work. I know this is a strange question.

EDIT: I don't drive to work and even the conference rooms have semi-transparent glass walls.

Comment: Do you have a shower room?

Comment: Do you drive to work? Maybe you could do it in your car.

Comment: Do you have a first aid room in your building? This should give you the privacy you need and the means to wash up afterwards.

Comment: Have you thought about leaving an hour early and go to the doctors office or anywhere outside of work and apply your cream there?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the toilets don't have covers"? Surely the toilets are designed to be sat on. You can still sit on them while wearing your trousers.

Comment: @thelem that's not the case in all countries ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> I guess I can go to a bathroom stall and do it, but it would be a
>   balancing act as the toilets don't have covers to sit on.
>
> Any suggestions?

Either find an empty conference room, first aid room, or other room without windows and do it there, or go into the toilet and be careful.

Worst case, do it in your car.

Since it should only take a short time, it should not be a huge deal either way.

Answer (score -2):

Under no circumstances tell your supervisor or anybody within the company.  Right now, only you know that what you have is not a notifiable infection or condition. I can see that you would be instantly, and unfairly, ostracised if word got out in the workplace that you have a condition so bad that (so the gossip may go) even your doctor insists on a "pre-treatment" before he sees you.

Can you see that nobody would want to touch you or go near you if they heard the inevitable gossip which always results from just one person knowing - and then word will always spread no matter how "sincere" the promise is that your secret is safe?

That would cost your social life dearly.  Possibly also your job, and all because word leaked out and gossip tends to grow as it is passed along, and the reaction of "the herd" won't be good for you.

This answer directly addresses your question of "any suggestions?"

What to do about the logistics of getting the cream on your foot, has already been suggested in answers and comments.

Comment: You could be right, but it sounds like you're reading too much into this.

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk. I take your point well.  It is a valid one, I have spent my whole life reading much into circumstances.  Sometimes I avert disaster, sometimes I get told what you just wrote.  All good. I sleep with a clear conscience that I have done my "bit" whether it's too much or not. Pretty sure you may have opportunity to make the same comment about me over a number of Stackexchange subjects.  I'm happy with that. Nice to make your acquaintance